# Time complexity in Big-O

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

What would be the BigO time of this algorithm

```
Input: Array A sorting n>=1 integers
Output: The sum of the elements at even cells in A
s=A[0]
for i=2 to n-1 by increments of 2
{
s=s+A[i]
}
return s
```

I think the function for this equation is F(n)=n*ceiling(n/2) but how do you convert that to bigO

Comment: Why do you think it's `n*ceiling(n/2)`?

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity for that algorithm would be `O(n)`, since the amount of work it does grows linearly with the size of the input. The other way to look at it is that loops over the input once - ignore the fact that it only looks at half of the values, that doesn't matter for Big-O complexity).

Answer (score 2):

The number of operations is not proportional to `n*ceiling(n/2)`, but rather `n/2` which is `O(n)`.  Because of the meaning of big-O, (which includes the idea of an arbitrary coefficient), `O(n)` and `O(n/2)` are absolutely equivalent - so it is always written as `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an O(n) algorithm since you look at ~n/2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm will do N/2 iterations given that there are N elements in the array. Each iteration requires constant time to complete. This gives us O(N) complexity, and here's why.

Generally, the running time of an algorithm is a function f(x) from the size of data. Saying that f(x) is O(g(x)) means that there exists some constant c such that for all sufficiently large values of x f(x) <= cg(x). Easy to see how this applies in our case: if we assume that each iteration takes a unit of time, obviously f(N) <= 1/2N.

Answer (score 0):

A formal manner to obtain the exact number of operations and your algorithm's order of growth:

[image]